# Preventing an app from progressing if a service is not enabled

Tags: android, service, gps

I am creating an Android app that uses GPS. I want to prompt the user to turn on the location services and prevent program from progressing unless they are turned on. I tried using a while loop but for some reason it does not work and I get an out of memory error. Any ideas about how to achieve such a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't block the UI thread for long, or else you'll get the dreaded ANR (Application Not Responding) dialog. GUI frameworks like Android are event-based. So use a dialog to inform the user about the prerequisite and `finish()` your Activity on click of the dialog's OK button.